# Change to one Image with a button

Tags: javascript, html

All images show up at once. I am attempting to try to change to 1 of the 3 images but all the images still show up, I'm not sure what i am doing wrong, thanks for any help in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Picture Change</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="picchange.css">
<script> 

function changeImage()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.src="tool1.jpg";
return false;
}

function changeImage2()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image2");
img.src="tool2.jpg";
return false;
}

function changeImage3()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image3");
img.src="tool3.jpg";
return false;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="image" src="tool1.jpg">
<img id="image2" src="tool2.jpg">
<img id="image3" src="tool3.jpg">

<br><br><br>
<p><input type="button" id="image" value="tool1!" onclick="changeImage()"></p>
<p><input type="button" id="image2" value="tool2!" onclick="changeImage()"></p>
<p><input type="button" id="image3" value="tool3" onclick="changeImage()"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have already injected all three images into the DOM. so they're going to render.  You have two nodes with the ID 'image2' BTW

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the images? On a side note, you shouldn't have html controls with the same id like `<img>` with `id="image"` and `<input>` with the same `id="image"`.

Comment: @JorgeAltieri I am trying to push a certain button and an image appears. Tool1 2 and 3 should appear only when I press a button, thank you :)

Comment: so initially don't assign any `src` to the image element and call the respective function on each button and assign the `src` to the respective image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/wcqoLvt0/8/

HTML

```
<img src="" id="image" />
<br><br><br>
<p><input type="button" id="image" value="tool1" onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/100x100')"></p>
<p><input type="button" id="image2" value="tool2" onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/150x150')"></p>
<p><input type="button" id="image3" value="tool3" onclick="changeImage('http://placehold.it/200x200')"></p>
```

JS

```
function changeImage(arg) {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  image.src=arg;
}
```